# weird braces/bracket symbol at the end of my output. (my program is on printing out the next alphabet).

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char input, letter1,letter2;

cout << "Enter a letter: ";
cin >> input;

if ( (input >= 'A' && input >= 'Z') || (input <= 'a' && input <= 'z') )
{
    if ( (input >= 'A' && input >= 'X') || (input <= 'a' && input <= 'x') )
    {
        letter1 = input + 1;
        letter2 = input + 2;
        cout << "Your letter trio today is " << input << letter1 << letter2<<".\n";  
    }

    else if ( input == 'Y' || input == 'y' )
    {
        letter1 = input + 1;
        cout << "Your letter trio today is " << input << letter1 <<".\n";    
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Your letter trio today is " << input <<".\n";
    }
}

}
```

if I input y, my output becomes yz{. If I input Y, my output becomes YZ[. If I input Z, my output becomes Z[. Any ideas? thanks guys

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using a debugger?

Comment: Thanks for the time and reply man, I haven't used a debugger yet, I was mainly wondering if there was anything wrong with my code. I actually asked my prof about this, the answer he gave me was pretty vague, he said my values were too large and needed to output separately. I have no clue what he meant.

Comment: Think a little harder about your conditions.

Comment: Another hint - if you use unique messages in each of your branches you'd see quickly which one your code is executing (and that should tell you which of your conditions are wrong)

Comment: hey thanks molbdnilo, do you care to be a little bit more clear? I have spent lots of time thinking but still can't find the solution. It's 3:35 here, this thing is dude 9 tomorrow. Coming here was my last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the ASCII representation of characters! C++ standard only requires that representation of digits are contiguous, but most common implementation use ASCII. The ASCII code for Y is 0x59. 0x59+1 is 0x5A the ASCII code of Z. And just guess what is the character with ASCII code 0x5B? Yes it is **`[`** so your output is normal...

The same, ascii code of lower case y is 0x79, and ascii code of `{` is 0x7B